# Request URI - If URL contains X & does Not contain Y - then do something

Tags: php, uri, stripos

Hi there my current code looks like this:

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'cake') !== false) 
        {echo '<div class="clear"></div><a href="http://www.example.com/cakes/" class="btn"> >> View all Cakes</a>';}
```

This works well to check if the current URL contains the word 'cake' and Then display a link to all cakes.

What I need to add to this is:

**If URL contains 'cake' but does not contain 'carrot' Then display a link to all cakes.**

Any ideas on how I can modify?

Many Thanks

Comment: Just add an other condition in your if, or add a second if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code :

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'cake') == true && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'carrot') == false) 
        {echo '<div class="clear"></div><a href="http://www.example.com/cakes/" class="btn"> >> View all Cakes</a>';}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more condition:

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'cake') !== false && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'carrot') === false) {
    echo '<div class="clear"></div><a href="http://www.example.com/cakes/" class="btn"> >> View all Cakes</a>';
}
```