# Check requested url for a text pattern then do something

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube

I am using the code below to execute video shortcode on my WordPress website but some pages already contain manually added video which will cause duplicate when i use the code.

How can include a check if the page already contain a YouTube embedded iframe or video link and exclude pages which already have videos, here is what i have below:

```
if (is_single() && in_category(1) ) 
{
 echo '<h4 class="post-title entry-title">Video</h4>' ;
 echo do_shortcode( '[yotuwp type="keyword" id="'.get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id, 'raw' ).'" player="mode=large" template="mix" column="1" per_page="1"]' );
}
```

I want to include youtube link check here:

```
 if (is_single() && in_category(1)
```

Here is what i am able to find [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244509/request-uri-if-url-contains-x-does-not-contain-y-then-do-something) but this scans the requested url instead of the content on it:

```
<?php
  if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'tout') == true && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'dedans') == true) 
    {echo '<div class="clear"></div><a href="http://www.example.com/cakes/" class="btn"> >> View all Cakes</a>';}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you already have the `$post_id` I suggest you get the Post object and do a regular expression match for 'youtube' or the short URL version 'youtu.be'. See sample code:

```
$post = get_post($post_id);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);

if (is_single() && in_category(1) && !preg_match('/youtu\.?be/', $content)) {
    echo '<h4 class="post-title entry-title">Video</h4>';
    echo do_shortcode('[yotuwp type="keyword" id="' . get_post_field('post_title', $post_id, 'raw') . '" player="mode=large" template="mix" column="1" per_page="1"]');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), like this:

```
if (strpos(file_get_contents($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 'youtube') === false) {
    // you can add your video
}
```

Comment: Which could also possibly match just a wording like "this is my youtube video" string.
I should rather recommend to first hook on "the_content" filter, then use a regex to be sure to match the wanted shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand you to hook on `the_content` filter to check the current content if already has the wanted shortcode, if not, add it.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'func_53829055', 10 );
/**
 * Check if the shortcode exists, if not, add it
 *
 * @param string $post_content
 *
 * @return string
 */
function func_53829055( $post_content ) {
    // Add your custom conditions
    if( ! is_single() && ! in_category( 1 ) ) {
         return $post_content;
    }

    // Use a regex or strpos depending on the needs and post_content length/complexity
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_content, '[yotuwp' ) ) {
        // It already has the wanted shortcode, then return the post content
        return $post_content;
    }

    // If add the video before post content
    $before  = '<h4 class="post-title entry-title">Video</h4>';
    $before .= do_shortcode( 'my_shortcode' );
    $before .= '<br />';

    $post_content = $before . $post_content;

    // If add the video after post content
    $post_content .= '<br />';
    $post_content .= '<h4 class="post-title entry-title">Video</h4>';
    $post_content .= do_shortcode( 'my_shortcode' );

    return $post_content;
}
```

Note that the priority has to be lower than 11, because shortcodes are replaced on 11 : `add_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11 );`